# how to decide proper disparity value for stereo vision

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I am doing a project on stereo vision, basically the system should estimate the distance in real time to avoid collision. The thing is i am not able to decide the proper baseline value . in formula what is the value of disparity.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the formula that relates a baseline to disparity

```
D=focal*Baseline/z
```

where focal length is in pixels, Baseline is in mm and z, a distance along the optical axis, is also in mm. Pick your Baseline so that you have a few pixels of disparity at the longest working distance. Also keep in mind that though a long Baseline will accomplish this, at a closer distance you would have a lager dead zone where the cameras' field of views do not overlap enough to have a meaningful disparity calculation.

Also, when selecting the resolution for your images don't go too high since a stereo processing is very intensive and a higher resolution may have stronger noise. Typically people don't use color in stereo matching for the same reason. For your task, the algorithm that uses gray VGA images and works at least at 20 fps with a Baseline = 40-60 cm may be a reasonable choice given vehicle speed <40mph.